# Laplacian in different coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, differential-forms, laplacian

Lets consider the following coordinates on $\Bbb R^3$:
$$x_1=r\cos(\xi),x_2=r\sin(\xi) w_2,x_3=r\sin(\xi) w_3$$
with $w_2^2+w_3^2=1,r=||x||$ and $0\leq \xi\leq \pi$. Further let $f$ be a function on $\Bbb R^3$ depending only on $r$ and $\xi$. I want to calculate the Laplacian of $f$ in the coordinates above.

In the paper I am reading this Laplacian is given but I dont get how they do it. It only says that $$dx_1^2+dx_2^2+dx_3^2=dr^2+r^2d\xi^2+r^2\sin(\xi)^2(dw_2^2+dw_3^2)$$ and therefore, since $\Delta f=\frac{1}{\sqrt g}\sum_k \partial_k(\sum_i g^{ik}\sqrt g\partial_if)$,
$$\Delta f=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}f+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{1}{\sin(\xi)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\sin(\xi)\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}f.$$
Could someone explain in some more detail what is happening here? What do I have to calculate? Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:**
I am able to obtain the first equation now since
$$dx_1=\cos(\xi)dr-r\sin(\xi)d\xi\\
dx_2=\sin(\xi)w_2dr+r\cos(\xi)w_2d\xi+r\sin(\xi)dw_2\\
dx_3=\sin(\xi)w_3dr+r\cos(\xi)w_3d\xi+r\sin(\xi)dw_3$$
so that
$$dx_1^2+dx_2^2+dx_3^2=dr^2+r^2d\xi^2+r^2\sin(\xi)^2(dw_2^2+dw_3^2)$$
follows be squaring each row and using $w_2^2+w_3^2=\cos(\xi)^2+\sin(\xi)^2=1$. Now if I use the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&r^2&0\\
0&0&r^2\sin(\xi)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$ as matrix tensor $g=g_{ij}dx_i\otimes dx_j$ in the new coordinates I obtain the desired result by the formula for the Laplacian above.

However I am not sure how rigorous this is since $dr,d\xi,dw_2,dw_3$ don't form a basis of the cotangent bundle since we have the restriction $w_2^2+w_3^2=1$ (note that I also only added one $r^2\sin(\xi)^2$ term on the diagonal of $g$ despite I have it for $w_2$ and $w_3$). Do I have to write $w_2,w_3$ as $\cos(t),\sin(t)$ at first, so that I have the same number of variables or is there another way?

Comment: Well, the problem, as you correctly pointed out, is that $r$, $\xi$, $w_1$ and $w_2$ are not coordinates (they are four and $\mathbb R^3$ is three-dimensional). The proper way to do this is to write $w_1=\cos t$ and $w_2=\sin t$. Nevertheless the expression you gave for $ds^2$ in terms of these functions is correct (it does not matter if the differential $dw_1$ and $dw_2$ are not independent).